# Running a method in angular using ng-init

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, in-app-purchase

I am fairly new to angular, I am making an app which has in app purchases.  The current method I have for loading in the products is being called through using ng-click. What I want is for this method to be called when the page loads so I have tried using ng-init but unfortunately this doesn't work.

Below is the links to the code I have tried and used:
https://gyazo.com/645e9a0554aab8d11f6d96b2b159a833
https://gyazo.com/68d305ab5ffdbf94db4cda5539313947

Thanks in advance

Comment: make a function in your controller and call it . it will load on controller load

Comment: Hi! Instead of posting images of code or error messages, copy and paste or type the actual code or message into the post directly. It will likely help people in understanding and reproducing your problem, which will increase the chances of getting an answer! :)

Comment: Hi Himesh, thank you for your response. I have added the following: https://gyazo.com/02042e67d84f35e5dccef643c687ae7e

And in my html file I called this: https://gyazo.com/ad259603296e704264596d63f0a85435

Although this still doesn't work, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ionic will automatically load anything inside the controller when a user goes to that page.

```
.controller('LoadItemsCtrl', function($scope) {

loadItems();

function loadItems(){

//Code Here

}

})
```